How to extract key and value values ​contained in listHashMap and insert other data java
I have maps of the kind:
HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, String>>> listMap  = new HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, String>>>();
This is what the listMap I have contains. :
{02=[{NUM_ID=02, VALUE=11.229, V_ID=A10001}, {NUM_ID=02, VALUE=-11.23, V_ID=B10002}],
03=[{NUM_ID=03, VALUE=-14.1123, V_ID=A10001}, {NUM_ID=03, VALUE=0.9, V_ID=B10002}]
04=[{NUM_ID=04, VALUE=-32.23, V_ID=A10001}, {NUM_ID=04, VALUE=-22, V_ID=B10002}]}}
Compare the key values ​​and if there is no number 01, you must set data number 02 to number 01.
What are some ways to compare key values?
please any answer.
